# How do I set up multiple virtual Machines for home server?

Tags: linux, ip, virtual-machine, hypervisor

I have been using linux, CentOS with a web hosting company for about a year now and I just got a good computer for free that can handle virtualization and 64 bit.

I have never had to set up my own server like how I want to now. I want to have 3 OS running at the same time.

I think I need to install a bare-metal type-1 hypervisor and then install CentOS 6.4 Server, Windows Server (any year), and a Windows 7 Home Premium.

I need more experience with VMs and Server products.

How do I go about setting this up? I also want to be able to manage the machines on my internal home ip and no need for much external ip except for applying updates.

I was thinking of using vmware or proxmox but dont know where to begin. My biggest need of help is setting up a hypervisor (no domain name, just ips) and be able to access it thru a webgui to manage the 3 above server installs as VMs and webgui via local IP range from my home router.

Please help me get started.

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always been a fan of VMWare ESXi for scenarios like this, and would highly recommend it.  The setup process is fairly easy if your hardware supports it.  You can download ESXi 5.1 for free here: https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=free-esxi5&lp=default.

I prefer to go the hypervisor route primarily for its simplicity from a support perspective.  I want my time and resources spent working with the virtualized servers, not the physical one.  Being able to call up another host 'on demand' is great, especially if you are testing software/etc and don't want to put something together.

As far as management, VMWare also provides management tools for ESXi, that give you the ability to manage just about all aspects of VMWare, as well as access the virtual console for those machines.  It makes creating new VMs (or managing existing) a breeze.  I'm not sure I'd use it beyond setup (I use RDP or VNC), but it's still very well featured.

Comment: I am downloading this vmware sphere. I see there are more than one download, including tools and client. Do you know what these do?

Comment: The tools/client are things you'll use to interface with the Hypervisor.  You'll definitely want the client as you'll need this to define VMs, etc once the Hypervisor is online.  Starting out, the client is likely all you need (in addition to the Hypervisor of course).

Comment: So will that include a localhost type webgui?

Comment: Yes.  When you select a Virtual Machine defined within the vSphere client, there is a 'console' tab that represents the virtual console.  From there you can access the console as you would if you were sitting in front of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of virtualistion solutions try some of them and decide wich one fits your needs (ex.):

- VMWare
- qemu
- VirtualBox
- Xen

Comment: Just realized that my computer is fully compatible for vm set up EXCEPT Mother board BIOS for some reason doesnt give me option to set it to YES.

I am using MB: a8n-sli premium

I think I need to do a bios upgrade or something. IDK.